# kernel TCP/IP implementation - about accept queue length

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm recently learning the TCP/IP implementation in linux kernel(version 4.4), and got really confused about the accept queue. I know there is a queue in `struct inet_connection_sock` which is called a **accept queue**:

```
struct inet_connection_sock {
    ...
    /* @icsk_accept_queue:     FIFO of established children */
    struct request_sock_queue icsk_accept_queue;
    ...
}
```

and there is a `qlen` member in it, I think it is used to indicate the length of the queue.

```
struct request_sock_queue {
    ...
    /* length of the queue? */
    atomic_t        qlen;
    ...
};
```

Here is what I think I know: when a LISTEN socket receives a SYN packet, in function [`tcp_conn_request`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6298), [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L638) is called to put the newly created NEW_SYN_RECV sock into ehash table (not `icsk_accept_queue`)

```
void inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add(struct sock *sk, struct request_sock *req,
                   unsigned long timeout)
{
    reqsk_queue_hash_req(req, timeout);  // add to ehash table
    inet_csk_reqsk_queue_added(sk);      // increment icsk_accept_queue.qlen
}
```

But in this funcfion, [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_added`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/include/net/inet_connection_sock.h#L282) is called to increment `icsk_accept_queue.qlen`. My question is why increment `qlen` since nothing is inserted to `icsk_accept_queue`? Is it not the length of icsk_accept_queue?

Also, [`tcp_conn_request`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6291) called [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_add`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L793) to add a fast open sock(if enabled) to `icsk_accept_queue`:

```
struct sock *inet_csk_reqsk_queue_add(struct sock *sk,
                      struct request_sock *req,
                      struct sock *child)
{
    struct request_sock_queue *queue = &inet_csk(sk)->icsk_accept_queue;

    spin_lock(&queue->rskq_lock);
    if (unlikely(sk->sk_state != TCP_LISTEN)) {
        inet_child_forget(sk, req, child);
        child = NULL;
    } else {
        req->sk = child;
        req->dl_next = NULL;
        if (queue->rskq_accept_head == NULL)
            queue->rskq_accept_head = req;
        else
            queue->rskq_accept_tail->dl_next = req;
        queue->rskq_accept_tail = req;
        sk_acceptq_added(sk);    // increment sk.sk_ack_backlog
    }
    spin_unlock(&queue->rskq_lock);
    return child;
}
```

But this function ended up incrementing `sk.sk_ack_backlog` (by calling [`sk_acceptq_added`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/include/net/sock.h#L791)) instead of `icsk_accept_queue.qlen`. Why not?

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question ? if so please post it here because i'm confused too about this topic.